# html email alignment issue

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to send out an html email.

```
<table width="180" border="0">
<tr>
 <td>
   <img src="image.jpg" width="180">
   <table border="0" width="180" border="2" height="100">
     <tr>
       <td width="10"></td>
       <td width="160"></td>
       <td width="10"></td>
     </tr> 
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

However the image in this case is not aligned with the table. Is this because of the 2px border? How do I align them? I need the 2px border. Any thoughts?

Comment: You've not included the potentially important information of which email client you're testing with.

Comment: Be more descriptive about what you want and what you see!  Not aligned how?

Comment: Apart from anything else, your code isn't properly nested at the moment. Why do you have another <table> tag before closing the previous one?

Comment: I am trying to test with a variety of clients. The only place where this bumps out is Outlook 2007. :(

Comment: @Sparky672 I had the same trouble as you. As both the image and the nested table (no comments...) have the same fixed width, I guessed he wanted to make the image line up with the table contents. (As table has extra 2px border.)

Comment: @ChrisW: You've apparently not had the misfortune to deal with pages designed using nested tables :) It sucks, but it's not invalid.

Comment: Why do you have two `border` attributes? `<table border="0" .. border="2" ..>`..

Comment: @ChrisW, what's not proper about putting a complete table inside of a table cell?  It gets ugly but the code is valid.

Comment: @ANeves, my comment to the OP is not for my benefit... it's to get him to write his question better for everyone's benefit.

Comment: @thirtydot, Sparky672: in all honesty, I didn't see the fact that both tables were closed; I thought there was only 1 </table> tag in the code snippet.  I haven't ever had to deal with the misfortune of dealing with nested tables.  They sound horrible ;) with some clever use of colspan / rowspan / <col> tags (which I learnt about recently and can be very useful in some circumstances), I'm sure nested tables could be eliminated

Comment: @ChrisW, unless I'm tabulating data, I don't use a table.  However, if one is misguided enough to still be using tables for page layouts, nesting them is almost inevitable in that case.

Comment: Btw, @user544079, remember to fill in the image's `alt` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="180" style="margin:0 0 0 2px;padding:0;display:block" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give the image 2px margin right and left, and make it allign with the table:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="180" style="margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;">
```

Comment: Wrong.  `margin: 2px 0;` is shorthand for a 2 pixel **top/bottom** margin and **no** right/left margin at all.

Comment: Try margin: 0 0 0 2px;  or margin-left: 2px

Comment: @Sparky672 no. I just tried it again in Firebug, `margin: 2px 0;` is shorthand for 2px left and right and 0px top and bottom. But if that confusion is a concern, one can use `margin: 0px 2px 0px 2px` for top/right/bottom/left.

Comment: @Aneves, the only confusion is yours since you're factually wrong about this.  See [the W3C Box Model spec and scroll down towards the end of the 8.3 section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties), _"If there are two values, the **top and bottom margins are set to the first value** and the right and left margins are set to the second."_.  [http://jsfiddle.net/B7U5N/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/B7U5N/2/).

Comment: @Sparky672 You are absolutely correct, thanks for the patience. (Answer corrected.) I don't understand how I could get it wrong **twice**, even though I checked both times with Firebug to be sure.